# Call to a member function getWsdlContent() on a non-object SOAP V2

Tags: soap-api-v2, magento-1.9.2.0

I'm working on a site on Magento 1.9.2.0. I can connect to the SOAP API but I cannot connect to SOAP V2. When I try and access it, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getWsdlContent() on a non-object in /chroot/home/examplesite/examplesite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Adapter/Soap.php on line 67
```

I have a fresh test install on our local server and the code is exactly the same, so I'm not sure exactly where this is failing or how to fix it. The end result is the infamous "Cannot load external entity" error.

The server is using PHP 5.4.45 based on another StackOverflow's suggestion that the latest version of PHP would resolve the issue.

I need to be able to access SOAP V2 in order to integrate with our marketing company. Our server company is Nexcess and they are not willing to assist because they state it's an application error; any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Th WSDL config Object is initialized in the protected Varien_Object Constructor here: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php#L57

the Method it calls is implemented here: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Adapter/Soap.php#L41

if it would not be able to load the Model, the Error would already be here: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Adapter/Soap.php#L44

This means that, for some Reason, the _construct Method is never called. Do you have any Custom Modules extending the Soap Adapter or maybe even changing Varien_Object?

Did you maybe add a custom __construct Method to any of the classes and did not call parent::__construct() inside? same with _construct()